# Entropy Change in Two-Component System Transferring Internal Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

In example 14.2 of Blundell and Blundell's text, "Concepts in Thermal Physics", the authors say the following -

"Consider two systems, with pressures $p_1$ and $p_2$ and temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$. If internal energy $\Delta U$ is transferred from system 1 to system 2, and volume $\Delta V$ is transferred from system 1 to system 2, find the change in entropy.

$\textit{Solution:}$

The equation $dU = TdS - pdV$ can be written as

$$dS = \frac{1}{T}dU + \frac{p}{T}dV. \quad (1)$$

If we now apply this to our problem, the change in entropy is then straightfowardly

$$ \Delta S = \biggl(\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2}\biggr)\Delta U + \biggl(\frac{p_1}{T_1} - \frac{p_2}{T_2}\biggr) \Delta V. \quad (2)"$$

I can't quite rationalize the expressions in parentheses in (2). I would think the expression for $\Delta S$ would be the sum of $\Delta S$ for the first system and $\Delta S$ for the second system - i.e.,

$$ \Delta S = \biggl( \frac{1}{T_1} + \frac{1}{T_2}\biggr)\Delta U + \biggl(\frac{p_1}{T_1} + \frac{p_2}{T_2}\biggr) \Delta V$$

Why is my intuition wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: hint: $\Delta U_1+\Delta U_2=0$ and $\Delta V_1+\Delta V_2=0$

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you! One thing - in my final expression for $\Delta S$ I now have $\Delta U_1$ and $\Delta V_1$. Is this what the authors meant to write? Presumably $\Delta U$ and $\Delta V$ in (2) aren't to be interpreted as $\Delta U_1 + \Delta U_2$ and $\Delta V_1 + \Delta V_2$

Comment: hint:$\Delta S = \Delta S_1+\Delta S_2$